# Drupal Site configuration issues

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

Good day every one,
I am new in DRUPAL.
I am having problem with the drupal site. 
I got the repository for the drupal site. I have successfully clone it and got every things and the database. I have uploaded the database to the local host server. 
Now, I can see that initially the directory is like this
C:\wamp\www\test\site\docroot\sites\default\

Then when i first open the site through local host the directory automatically becomes like this
C:\wamp\www\test\site\docroot\sites\default\file

The "file" directory contains the empty folder of css, images etc/
which I believe is downloaded from the database for the first time.

The site is giving many console error like missing images etc. 
Instead of having the empty folder in file directory there must be images and css files and everything I do not know what is wrong becs the folder should not be empty there must be files and and image sand css files and should be downloaded from the database when I first open the site.

Please help me to locate the problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you will put on git drupal core, modules and theme files.., basically everything except the files uploaded by user (admin). Those files are usually located at:

```
/sites/default/files
```

So, since they are not on git repo you need to copy them to your local environment from the working site (i.e. over (S)FTP).

If your "file" is not "files" dir I'm talking about then it's something specific to your site - don't know nothing about it.